# how to deleting table rows during a backup

Tags: sql-server

my tool is deleting data from a table and it takes a lot of time 1/2 days,
meanwhile there are scheduled backups, 
can sql server handle this situation or is better to stop the tool?
I can't try the tool because i don't have enough time

Comment: You must be deleting a lot of data? What does your table structure look like? What indexes do you have on your table? What does your where clause on your delete look like? How many rows are in the table and how many rows are you deleting? With more information we may be able to help you. You may want to ask how to speed up your delete by perhaps deleting in batches (TOP) / using indexes etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to SQL Server jobs that are scheduled during a backup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258435/what-happens-to-sql-server-jobs-that-are-scheduled-during-a-backup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server backups are online, so there is no need to stop your processes during a backup.

However the backup must contain the log records for transactions that occur during the backup, so that the database can be recovered to a consistent state when restoring the backup.

So if your delete process runs in one big transaction, the backup can't complete until it has captured all the log records up to the point when you commit or rollback the long running transaction.  So to avoid large backup files and long-running backups, you may want to not take backups while it's running.

But if it commits a series of smaller transactions, it should be fine to take backups while it's running.